# How to store null fields with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, nosql

[Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) does not store null/empty fields by default.  Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the interests of answering the question asked, you can:

- store **nulls** by configuring [`MapperOptions.setStoreNulls(boolean)`](https://morphia.dev/morphia/1.6/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.html#setStoreNulls(boolean))
- store **empty values** by configuring [`MapperOptions.setStoreEmpties(boolean)`](https://morphia.dev/morphia/1.6/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.html#setStoreEmpties(boolean)).

You can get a `MapperOptions` reference from the mapper instance by [`Mapper.getOptions()`](https://morphia.dev/morphia/1.6/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/Mapper.html#getOptions()).

#### Deprecation Update

However, the `Mapper` class is internal only and is deprecated:

> this class will be internalized in 2.0

Same deprecation applies for before mentioned setter methods in class `MapperOptions`, instead the JavaDocs recommend:

> use the Builder instead

Comment: Yeah its probably a code smell, as in my case, if you need to store null values in a document store.  But this is definitely the answer to my question.

Comment: Improved formatting and updated according to [your commit "created a builder for MapperOptions" from Dec 2018](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/commit/ba59808bcfa93ac6b5e85d4ad2e9e9871e80bc4e) which apparently was released with Morphia 1.5.3

Comment: For **Morphia 2.0** and above, see [this answer explaining the   `MapperOptions.Builder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010039/5730279).

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature and one of the points of a document store. Don't waste space (both on RAM, disk, and for transfers) on missing data.

If you use primitive types instead of object types, a value will be saved, since there's no null value. For example `long` instead of `Long`. For `String` you'd need to store an empty (or some dummy) value.

Out of interest: Why would you want to explicitly store null / empty fields? Maybe there's a better solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah after considering my problem, I don't think its necessary to store null/empty fields. I was stuck in relational mode.

Comment: Indexing can get weird if you index on a field that may or may not be in a document so it's beneficial sometimes to store them.

Comment: "weird" == a query using the index will never return a document where the indexed field is null, right? But are dummy values so helpful (especially in terms of performance)?

Comment: Actually pre-populating the field can increase performance when the field is eventually written to as it won't be necessary to replace the document in memory. So it depends on the use of the field. If it's null and will never be changed, then don't set it, if the field is likely to be changed in the future and is frequently accessed, then pre-populate it.

Comment: are you talking about the index or growing dicuments, which need to be moved on the disk?

Answer (score 0):

To allow null or empty values for fields, you can configure the Mapper behavior trough `MapperOptions`, as already [answered by evanchooly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28068454/5730279) (main contributor to Morphia).

#### Use `MapperOptions.Builder`

Since version 2.0 use the [`MapperOptions.Builder`](https://morphia.dev/morphia/1.6/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.Builder.html) for that.
It has setter for both:

- `storeNulls(boolean)`
- `storeEmpties(boolean)`

Since Morphia version 2.0 the `MapperOptions` are **immutable**, but very powerful to control [mapping-behavior](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.1/mapping.html). To store null or empty values build the mapper-options as follows:

```java
String databaseName = "morphia_example";

MapperOptions options = MapperOptions.builder()
    .setStoreNulls(true)
    .setStoreEmpties(true)
    .build();

Datastore datastore = Morphia.createDatastore(databaseName, options)
```

#### See also

- [Introduce builder for MapperOptions · Issue #1134 · MorphiaOrg/morphia · GitHub](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/1134)